# Can't see Headers in Retrofit 2 logging

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 to make a network request and I want to add a header to it. After setting the headers I set a logging mechanism to see the log. This is what I see now, no headers in request.

```
07-19 18:17:41.553 23344-24481/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: --> GET http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/AMZN,GOOG,ORCL,%5ENDX,/quote?format=json&view=detail http/1.1
07-19 18:17:41.553 23344-24481/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: --> END GET
```

The response from the server:

```
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: <-- 406 Not Acceptable http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/TX60.TS,%5EGSPTSE,%5EIXIC,%5ENDX,%5EDJI,%5EGSPC,%5EBVSP,%5EMXX,%5EMERV,%5EIPSA/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail (342ms)
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 16:17:42 GMT
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: P3P: policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: content-length: 21
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Expires: -1
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Vary: X-Ssl
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Age: 0
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Via: http/1.1 yts278.global.media.ir2.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), http/1.1 media-router33.prod.media.ir2.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), http/1.1 r05.ycpi.dea.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Server: ATS
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
07-19 18:17:41.867 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
07-19 18:17:41.868 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: Y-Trace: BAEAQAAAAAALB1fOMgMOYgAAAAAAAAAAiBQMqkYf28UAAAAAAAAAAAAFN_9spyqfAAU3_2ynuqWCC3MYAAAAAA--
07-19 18:17:41.868 23344-24499/com.carlos.capstone.debug D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

Here are the classes involved:
I set a HeaderInterceptor where I set the headers to the request and after that the the logging.

```
public class IndexOrShortInfoRApi {
    public static IIndexOrShortInfoData myService;
    public interface IIndexOrShortInfoData {

        @GET("/webservice/v1/symbols/TX60.TS,^GSPTSE,^IXIC,^NDX,^DJI,^GSPC,^BVSP,^MXX,^MERV,^IPSA/quote?format=json&view=detail")
        Call<IndexOrShortInfoDataResponse> getIndexesAmerica();
        @GET("/webservice/v1/symbols/^STOXX50E,^FTSE,^GDAXI,^FCHI,^IBEX,FTSEMIB.MI,PSI20.LS,BEL20.BR,^BFX,^SSMI,OBX.OL,RTS.RS,OMXC20.CO,^OMXSPI,^SSMI,FPXAA.PR,GD.AT,^ATX,^ISEQ/quote?format=json&view=detail")
        Call<IndexOrShortInfoDataResponse> getIndexesEurope();
        @GET("/webservice/v1/symbols/^N225,000001.SS,^AXJO,^AORD,^HSI,^BSESN,^NSEI,^NZ50,^TWII,^JKSE,^KLSE,^KS11,^STI,PSEI.PS/quote?format=json&view=detail")
        Call<IndexOrShortInfoDataResponse> getIndexesAsia();
        @GET("/webservice/v1/symbols/{ticker}/quote?format=json&view=detail")
        Call<IndexOrShortInfoDataResponse> getSecurityShortInfoByTicker(@Path("ticker") String ticker);
    }

    public static IIndexOrShortInfoData getMyService(){
        //OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
        Dispatcher dispatcher=new Dispatcher();
        dispatcher.setMaxRequests(3);

        OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();

        if (myService==null) {
            Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://finance.yahoo.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
            myService=retrofit.create(IIndexOrShortInfoData.class);
            return myService;

        } else {
            return myService;
        }

    }
}
```

The class for setting the headers:

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request =chain.request();
        request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; MotoG3 Build/MPI24.107-55) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36")
                .build();
        Log.d("Retrofit", request.headers().toString());
        Response response=chain.proceed(request);
        return response;

    }
}
```

I can't even see the Log.d("Retrofit", request.headers().toString()). It seems that HeaderInterceptor class is not instantiating but I am not able to see where the error is. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I wasn't assigning the result of setting the headers to a variable, thus not including it in the request:

solution:

```
 request=request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; MotoG3 Build/MPI24.107-55) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36")
                .build();
        Log.d("Retrofit", request.headers().toString());
```